# Visual Studio - Adding Solution "Parts" to Toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a PLC programmer (mostly industrial automation using Ladder Logic) who has picked up some other programming skills along the way.  Went back to school, learned some basic C and java, etc.  But I'm a bit baffled by the Visual Studio IDE for C#.  I'm brand new to this, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have two sample applications and I've been assigned with trying to make one look/behave more or less like the other.  The "working" application, when I open it in VS 2019, has a customized section of the VS toolbox.  The toolbox contains all of the User Controls that appear in the "Parts" folder of the VS solution.  This allows me to drag and drop these controls into a Form and it auto-generates the code.  Nice.

However, on the other sample project (which is very similar) nothing from the "Parts" folder appears in the Toolbox.  So I can't drag and drop the Use Controls into the forms I'm trying to build.

Not sure if it matters, but I'm running the apps on two separate PCs so I can compare easily.  Both are running brand new installs of VS 2019.  I mention this because I didn't do any custom setup of the IDE.  So the fact that these items from the Parts folder appear in the VS Toolbox seems to be a function of the solution itself, not the IDE.

So that's my question: How do I get things from the Parts folder into the VS Toolbox so I can drag them into a form?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
$$$

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Compile the project successfully and anything that appears in the "Parts" folder will automatically appear in the toolbox under a new heading with the same title as your project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/workflow-designer/how-to-add-activities-to-the-toolbox?view=vs-2019
$$$

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.